# View another persons calendar details in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, calendar

I know how to view somebody else's calendar - there are 100 walk-throughs [like this one](http://oit.nd.edu/exchange/viewcalendar.shtml) on Google. However, this feature has changed in Outlook 2010, and you no longer get prompted for rights to view another person's calendar, and Outlook just displays their "Free/Busy" information, which doesn't help me.

I'd like to request permissions to view the details of their appointments, but I can't find any place to request permissions on their calendar - Outlook 2010 just gives me "Free/Busy" rights and then appears to have no option to request additional rights. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your calendar.
On the Ribbon click on "Share calendar".
This generates a (special) email.
Put in a recipient and then click the check box to request their permission to see their calendar. Optionally untick the one that shares yours with them.

Hope this helps

Comment: I assumed "Share Calendar" was about showing people my own calendar, but clearly it's about both. +15 to you.

Comment: This is another example of functionality in Office which is getting hidden through trying to simplify the interface. Even changing the name of the button to "Calendar Sharing" might have made this more discoverable.

Comment: Aye. I never would have found this without reading this post and its answer.

Comment: IME, this doesn't guarantee you receive a particular set of rights on their calendar. You can only specify what *you* want to share with them and hope they reciprocate.

Answer (score 2):

For Sysadmins:

From exchange, find the calander item and right click, choose "Manage Full Access" and click "Add" on the windo that appears. type in the username of the person requesting access to the calander and hit "ok". The user should be able to add the calander to their outlook client and see more specific information instead of just free/busy. I just tried this earlier on today for one of our staff and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to quickly see availability on a certain day without requesting access to their calendar, I use the following regularly:

1. Go to Calendar view
2. Choose "New Meeting"
3. Put the other persons outlook address in the "To:" field
4. Conflicts and available times appear on the right

[It looks like this](http://www.slipstick.com/mg/i/imgFF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a more efficient way to do this.  Since granting a user Full Access gives them abilities that they really don't need, I recommend just making them a `delagate` for that calendar. This is done in the `Properties` under the `Resource Policy` tab.  Just click `Add` under `Specify delegates of this mailbox` and select the users that need to view the calendar contents.